# roscpp template programming: get statically the Stamped message type

Tags: ros, c++, message

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to know if there is some method or trait class in (roscpp or another library) which allows getting the "associated stamped type" of a Type T. For instance

StampedType::type ::type

If it does not exist, IMO it should. Its a very interesting method to do generic programming in ROS.

BTW I've also missed message inheritance in ROS (but this is another issue where a lot of discussion it is possible)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/51207/roscpp-template-programming:-get-statically-the-stamped-message-type/) by [Pablo Iñigo Blasco](https://answers.ros.org/users/356/pablo-i%C3%B1igo-blasco/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2982 on 2012-12-29

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't know of any implementation of that method.  It might make an interesting library to contribute.  However there's no way to do it automatically as a stamped type is more of a convention, and not all messages have it.

In the tf datatypes you will find a Stamped<> templated datatype for each type of data supported.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-12-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pablo Iñigo Blasco](https://answers.ros.org/users/356/pablo-i%C3%B1igo-blasco/) on 2012-12-31**:
Yep I understand. It's a pitty that Stamped<> is only for tf messages and the only allowed types are statically set. Moreover it forces you to use a tfBroadacaster instead a generic ros msg publisher.

**Comment by [Pablo Iñigo Blasco](https://answers.ros.org/users/356/pablo-i%C3%B1igo-blasco/) on 2012-12-31**:
In any case it would be possible if there would be a template mechanism to generate msgs stamped datatypes. In that case Stamped would be a rosmsg type. In such case all the StampedMsgTypes would be unnecessary. The method ros::Publisher::publish might accept T or Stamped

**Comment by [Pablo Iñigo Blasco](https://answers.ros.org/users/356/pablo-i%C3%B1igo-blasco/) on 2012-12-31**:
The header data could be filled explicitly or implicitly by the ros::Publisher.   At the same time, a subscriber could use either T or Stamped . IMHO this could be possible maintaining the backwards compatibility.

**Comment by [Pablo Iñigo Blasco](https://answers.ros.org/users/356/pablo-i%C3%B1igo-blasco/) on 2012-12-31**:
The header data could be filled explicitly or implicitly by the ros::Publisher... I think that this could be possible maintaining the backwards compatibility. Using rosmsg infraestructure even would be possible to make compatible StampedPose with Stamped